# Getting values by pressing 'Enter' key rather than clicking a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a program in python(Tkinter) which takes username and password as input and a button which, when pressed, goes through a function which checks the username and password and further runs the program. I want that, rather than clicking the button, user presses the 'Enter' key and that does the function of the button. please help.

Comment: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Answer (score 4):

You can bind the `<Return>` event on the `Entry` widget with some method (which will do what you want):

```
# binding <Return> event

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as msg

def show(event=None): # handler
    msg.showinfo('name', 'Your name is ' + inp.get())

m = tk.Tk()

prompt = tk.Label(m, text='Name: ')
prompt.pack(fill='x', side='left')

inp = tk.Entry(m)
inp.bind('<Return>', show) # binding the Return event with an handler
inp.pack(fill='x', side='left')

ok = tk.Button(m, text='GO', command=show)
ok.pack(fill='x', side='left')

m.mainloop()
```

If you want to know more about *events* and *bindings*, see this [*effbot's page*](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm), which is quite easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll want to bind the  key to your handler: `frame.bind('<Return>', some_handler)`.

Comment: You probably wouldn't want to bind to the frame, you'd bind to the entry widget.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the normal binding to a function did not work. Probably because I am using it inside a class, I used the Lambda function and it worked. Here's the code:

inp.bind('', lambda _: show())